# Xamarin android - Attempt to invoke virtual method sendBroadcast() on a null object reference

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building a crossplatform application using Xamarin,my application will download videos from internet, I've done the download and save functions, but after saved videos to DCIM(in android) the videos do not appear in gallery.After hafl of a day searching for solutions on internet I comeup with two solutions:

1.after download finished: send broadcast with action "Intent.ActionMediaMounted".

2.after download finished Call "MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile".

With solution 1 I got:

"{Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference}

With solution 2, I got:

"{Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)' on a null object reference}

This is my Interface which I used to handle downloadfinished placed in PLC project:

```
namespace VideoDownloader
    {
      public interface IDownloadState
      {
          void OnDownloadStarted();
          void OnDownloadError();
          void OnDownloadFinished(string path);
       }
    }
```

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs in PLC project:

```
namespace VideoDownloader
{
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void downloadVideo(VideoInfor video, bool isRetried)
        {
          //download code here...                                    
          DependencyService.Get<IDownloadState()
          .OnDownloadFinished(video.path);
         }
    }

}
```

And This is my MainActivity in Android project which implement IDownloadState and send broadcast when OnDownloadFinished fired:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]
namespace VideoDownloader.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "VideoDownloader", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = 
"@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = 
ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, 
IDownloadState
    {
        readonly string[] StoragePermissions =
        {
            Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
            Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
        };

        const int RequestStorageId = 0;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            int sdkBuildVersion = (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt;
            Console.WriteLine("SDK build version = " + sdkBuildVersion);
            if (sdkBuildVersion >= 23)
            {
                RequestStoragePermission();
            }
        }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
                    string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestStorageId:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }


        public void OnDownloadStarted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnDownloadError()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnDownloadFinished(string path)
        {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaMounted);
            //SendBroadcast(intent);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(this, new String[] { 
              Android.OS.Environment
.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim)
.AbsolutePath }, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are many many similar questions for android on stackoverflow that have ansered but they seem to not like my situation at all. So is there anyone know what am I doing wrong? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With solution 2, I got:
>
> "{Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)' on a null object reference}

Please try to use `Forms.Context` instead of `this` in `OnDownloadFinished()`.
For example:

```
    public void OnDownloadFinished(string path)
    {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaMounted);
        //SendBroadcast(intent);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Forms.Context, new String[] {
        Android.OS.Environment        
.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim)
.AbsolutePath }, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: @user2905416 Have you tried to clean and rebuild? Or try to run it on a real phone.

Comment: I can debug my project now, that was Monodebuging was disabled in my visual studio and I've tried your solution "replace this with Forms.Context" the error disapear but when I open gallery, the video downloaded to DCIM folder not there, do you have any suggestions for gallery on android to be able to display the downloaded video file ?

Comment: @user2905416 Are you sure your video is downloaded? Could you provide a demo project?

Comment: @ Billy Liu - MSFT: I'm sure that the video was downloaded, because I'm using "Es file explorer File manager" to manage files and folder on my android simulator.How to provide you my demo project? an APK file?

Comment: @user2905416 you could upload the project to Github and give me the link

Comment: Here is my project on Github: https://github.com/hieuhtgc00378/Xamarin-VideoDownloader , do you have a skype,facebook,email... so that I can contact and learn from you about xamarin??? my skype is "hieuhtgc00378", my email is : hieuhtgc00378@gmail.com

Comment: @user2905416 I have tested your code and reproduce your issue. And I think it is the android problem, it will take sometime to add your download video to the Gallery, you could try to reboot your phone... Or you could download some video player to display the files.